# Does syslog-ng supports network namespaces?

Tags: syslog, syslog-ng

Does syslog-ng supports log forwarding to remote host in different a network namespaces?

Something similar to rsyslog [omfwd::NetworkNamespace](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfwd.html)

Answer (score -4):

Check out the syslog-ng documentation please but my best understanding is that the network() and syslog() destination drivers of syslog-ng provide roughly the same functionality.

The documentation for syslog-ng open source edition is published here:
https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/list/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.19

Comment: The link nowadays redirects to a commercial offering

Comment: Indeed, thanks for spotting this, I've just updated the links in the answer above.